# Appending line to file with Golang Package log, not getting a new line.

Tags: logging, go, io

I am using the golang package "log" when I use log to write to a text file, it does not append a new line of text to the end. It puts everything inline.

[This is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJQD.png)

[How I would like it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C7cO.png)

Current Code.

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("D:\\temp2\\testlogfile.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    Error.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
}
defer f.Close()
multi := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)
log.SetOutput(multi)
log.Println("testy1")
log.Println("testy2")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that you are opening the file with Notepad.

Comment: @Tim-Cooper You're correct. Thank you for that information. Do you know of a way to make it editor independent, if that is possible?

Comment: @Oyang use any editor that knows how to render `\n`.

Comment: Adding `\r` at the end of the string should work as well.

Comment: @IgorDubinskiy Breaking portability...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Sure, but not everyone needs portability. And I think many editors on Unix-like systems essentially ignore `\r` much like Notepad ignores `\n`.

Comment: @IgorDubinskiy Not on any of my machines. All of the text editors I use (vim both on Linux and OSX, Textmate) recognize Windows line endings. And I would not go so far to call Notepad an editor - it is more of a text file viewer with very limited modification capabilities. ;)

Comment: I used \r, it does what I need it to and works fine with the editors we use regularly. 

Thank you, @IgorDubinskiy.

Comment: I found my answer in your question. thank you

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned inside the comments, your editor doesn't understand unix-style ["LF"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) `\n` newlines. 
Consider using Notepad++

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Or something cross-platform like Atom, Sublime Text, or Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score -1):

I used \r for a carriage return. It works fine for all of the editors we use internally.

Comment: This is a really bad idea in general as it is not cross-platform.

Windows expects \r\n and unix expects \n. \r therefore would not work on *nix platforms. you might develop on windows right now but don't expect to do that for the rest of your life. building healthy habits early on is a good idea.

You won't need \r anywhere expect a windows-based text editor. Any code you execute should look for \n and any code you write should insert \n therefore regardless even if you're on windows the code will execute correctly and be cross-platform compatible.